# Can/should boolean values be passed in json with quotes?

Tags: json, boolean

I've read through a few questions on this and I'm still unclear. Which is correct:

```
{"some_parameter": "true"}
```

or

```
{"some_parameter": true}
```

I assume the second is the correct, *proper* way to send boolean values via json? But the first is still valid json...

The context here is that I'm building an API (used by some 3rd party applications) and I'm wondering if it's reasonable to simply disallow the first type altogether (reject with error) or accept boolean data as strings like this, and just attempt to handle (convert) them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Short answer**, yes that is the proper way to send the JSON. You should not be placing anything other than a string inside of quotes.

**Long answer**,

It depends on the data type. For the Key, yes you have to use quotes but only for strings. Also, you can use single quotes if you want to place a quotation mark inside of it. (or use escape)

```
'
```

for instance, 
vs

```
"
```

As for your bool value, if you want it to convert straight into a bool, than you do not need to include the quotes. Same for integers and double values.

But if you want to pass it as a string, than you will need to put it inside of quotes.

Generally, these types of questions are asked when you discuss what types of systems will be accepting your data.

It's generally much easier to use strings everywhere, but it's also extremely inefficient and results in your recipient needing to cast them if they want to do arithmetic with an int for instance, but it's passed as a string.

Comment: I think the answer then, is that there is no clear answer, unfortunately. I was hoping for a more decisive answer here ("No! No! don't *ever* try to pass true/false as "true" or "false"! that would be *crazy*" etc) alas.. ;)

Comment: I guess this explains my initial confusion

Comment: Sorry if my comment is complex, I'm trying to give the full picture here.

Short version, yes you are correct and enforcing JSON standards by not having a bool value inside of quotes.

I'll update, haha.

Comment: OK, I answered simply. Haha, sorry about that! I was trying to give you the entire picture of the scenarios, but ignore all of that. Just read Simple answer, and long answer, I answered your question in the simple than gave the full answer in the long answer :).

Comment: No worries; thanks for your answer. For my situation, I think I'll try to build the API in a way that it accepts both types (only boolean values, OR a string that is equal to either "true" or "false"). Then I've covered both angles.

Comment: You could easily get away with that by setting another variable as the intended variable, and then for the string version, put the set as {this._realValue=Convert.ToInt32(value);} and same for the int property, except {this._realValue = value;}

Make sense? And you'd place a [JsonIgnore] attribute also above the string version, if you only want to transmit the proper method.

So you'd have two variables, one int and one string, both accessing the same internal private property that is an integer. Both public variables (String,int) return this private. Then you [JsonIgnore] the string.

Comment: There are definately other more friendly approaches that people may recommend, such as a custom JSON Serializer, but I'd encourage you do get into the weeds a bit and work with this type of implementation first. That way, you can see exactly what's going on under the hood and if you're ever working some place that has this requirement, you'll better understand to tell them "JUST TAKE THE BOOL!!" :) (Because the string handling is very messy and unfriendly, compared to the simple bool in JSON)

Comment: I strongly resent the "It's generally much easier to use strings everywhere".

It is _always_ easier to leave the thinking to the next developer.  But the pain of the API designer ("should I string or should I bool?") is nothing compared to the pain of the 1000 consumer developers ("hey what, should this be a boolean?  Or can it be an it?  Or can I put 'santa' in this field?").

Comment: @xtofl like many things, a small degree of common sense is required. And while you can resent it, it's still generally easier for different systems. Especially if there's a difference of computation power between them. Also, in the realm of security - using strings to store different data types means an actual understanding of the system must be used. In further complexity, consider value A and value B as keys with string values. You won't know their significance if you're trying to break the system. You can also have a more fluid system design, say value of B changes based on what A contains

Comment: @JacobGaiski I have a small degree of common sense.  Allow me the freedom of, after decades of a recurring type of bugs caused by this postponing of usable API design, expressing the horror of a phrase starting with "easier to use strings".  Also in my experience, the second part of the sentence will be quickly forgotten by a majority of readers.

You are right, but on this forum, the last paragraph may incur the opposite effect of a warning sign.  _That_ is what I resent.  Drop the paragraph, and you'll be even more right!

Answer (score 9):

Boolean values must be passed without quotes. Boolean is one of the types supported by json: https://www.json.org/json-en.html and the expected values are true or false, without quotes.

It may still work with quotes when the receiving end parsing the data is a weak typing language like Javascript which converts the value automatically when you use it in a boolean context, but it's always better to follow what the standards say.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, We can pass Boolean value in Json. Just we need to write value in small case.
For Example

```json
{
        "fullName": "Deepak Dongre",
        "gender": true,
        "dob": "1986-11-16",
        "mobileNumber": 97959000321,
        "tblMstHobbyDetails": []
}
```

Comment: what gender it is when it's true? :DDD

Answer (score 0):

This is valid JSON and but it defines `some_parameter` as a string having the contents "true" and not as a boolean:

```
{"some_parameter": "true"}
```

This is also valid JSON which defines `some_parameter` as a boolean whose value is true:

```
{"some_parameter": true}
```

So if you want to send `some_parameter` as a real boolean, leave out the quotes.

Of course, which to use depends on what the receiving side is expecting and is able to parse correctly.